# How to do set diagrams (NOT Venn Diagrams - see image for an example) in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I'm trying to create a diagram to illustrate set relationships in Microsoft Word. I'll admit that I can't remember the actual name of this type of diagram and I've been having trouble finding out what it's called (in fact, if someone could remind me of its name I'd appreciate it).

As an illustration, the [Wikipedia article on bijections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection,_injection_and_surjection) has a diagram that looks like what I'm trying to do:
[image]

Or, more specifically, something like this:
[image]

Does Microsoft Word have a tool for this? My first thoughts were to use SmartArt or Equations Editor, but if it's possible to do that in those it's not obvious to me how. Or am I going to have to use the Drawing Canvass for this? (I'd rather not have to do that though because it seems like the diagram would be a lot more professional-looking if there was a built-in tool to do that specifically).

I unfortunately do *not* have Visio by the way.

Comment: I don'T think there would be a more specialized way for that than inserting smart art / drawing objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to draw it with the "Shapes" option on the Insert tab. That option has most of the tools you need in order to draw the diagram.

1. Oval for the set
2. Arrow lines
3. Text Boxes

In order to get the desired look you have to tweak each shape preferences: for the oval disable the shape fill and change line color. For the arrow choose the desired end arrow style. Once you have finished your diagram select all the components and "group" them in order to prevent unwanted changes while moving it around the document.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is the only way there is as far as I know. For better options; "MS Visio" or similar software.

Comment: @Hannu I was actually wondering the same thing. I've always thought it's a little rude to downvote without an explanation, if they disagree they should at least explain why.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but the reason *might* be that your answer is very short. If you could elaborate a bit further it would improve the quality of your answer and possibly get some more upvotes.

Comment: You probably got the the downvotes as your answer is too short, making it a low quality answer. While it's true, it doesn't show almost any effort you put to write it (explaining a bit more detailed why it's your opinion, or how it would work with shapes...). Currently it would better fit as a comment than an answer.

Comment: I reserve downvotes for *wrong* answers. Much better to give positive criticism for good starts.